# Directory bookmarking for bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Is there any directory bookmarking utility for bash to allow move around faster on the command line?

Comment: Take a look at autojump: https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump/wiki

Comment: Why is the question and your script bash specific? You should try avoiding *bash* scripts. Write *shell* scripts instead.

Comment: @Jens i used this [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Teach-Yourself-Shell-Programming-Hours/dp/0672323583) to do what i wanted to do.

Comment: This one's quite good, too. http://jeroenjanssens.com/2013/08/16/quickly-navigate-your-filesystem-from-the-command-line.html It even has auto-complete.

Answer (score 28):

Also, have a look at [CDPATH](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html)

A colon-separated list of search paths available to the cd command, similar in function to the $PATH variable for binaries. The $CDPATH variable may be set in the local ~/.bashrc file.

```
ash$ cd bash-doc
bash: cd: bash-doc: No such file or directory

bash$ CDPATH=/usr/share/doc
bash$ cd bash-doc
/usr/share/doc/bash-doc

bash$ echo $PWD
/usr/share/doc/bash-doc
```

and

```
cd -
```

It's the command-line equivalent of the back button (takes you to the previous directory you were in).

Comment: I prefer this solution since I have well organized directory structure.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks for sharing your solution, and I'd like to share mine as well, which I find more useful than anything else I've came across before.

The engine is a great, universal tool: [command-line fuzzy finder](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) by Junegunn.

It primarily allows you to “fuzzy-find” files in a number of ways, but it also allows to feed arbitrary text data to it and filter this data. So, the shortcuts idea is simple: all we need is to maintain a file with paths (which are shortcuts), and fuzzy-filter this file. Here's how it looks: we type `cdg` command (from "cd global", if you like), get a list of our bookmarks, pick the needed one in just a few keystrokes, and press Enter. Working directory is changed to the picked item:

[image: cdg]

It is extremely fast and convenient: usually I just type 3-4 letters of the needed item, and all others are already filtered out. Additionally, of course we can move through list with arrow keys or with vim-like keybindings `Ctrl+j`/`Ctrl+k`.

Article with details: [Fuzzy shortcuts for your shell](http://dmitryfrank.com/articles/shell_shortcuts).

It is possible to use it for GUI applications as well (via xterm): I use that for my GUI file manager [Double Commander](http://doublecmd.sourceforge.net/). I have plans to write an article about this use case, too.

Comment: Thank you thousand times for the `fzf` command! I have updated your answer with my simple `cdg` implementation. Hope it helps other people :)

Comment: @PetrÚjezdský, I think it'd be better if you just write your own answer; firstly, this will be more clear for the readers, and secondly, it'll be easier for both of us if one day you want to edit your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I think it will clutter the answers more. But, I did what you want. My simple `cdg` implementation can be found in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46268899/1310733). Happy `cd`ing to all :)

Comment: Thanks. I use it like this: add bookmark = `alias cdb='sort -u -o ~/.fzfcd <(pwd) ~/.fzfcd'`, fuzzy cd = `alias cdf='cd "$(fzf < ~/.fzfcd)"'`

Answer (score 8):

[Bashmarks](https://github.com/huyng/bashmarks/blob/master/bashmarks.sh) is an amazingly simple and intuitive utility.
In short, after installation, the usage is:

```
s <bookmark_name> - Saves the current directory as "bookmark_name"
g <bookmark_name> - Goes (cd) to the directory associated with "bookmark_name"
p <bookmark_name> - Prints the directory associated with "bookmark_name"
d <bookmark_name> - Deletes the bookmark
l                 - Lists all available bookmarks
```

Comment: The only change I had to make to this was change the name of the `l` function to something like `lb` because `l` is already an alias for a specific `ls` incantation in my bash shell. But yes, a very cool, intuitive and simple script!

Answer (score 7):

In bash script/command,
you can use `pushd` and `popd`

[pushd](http://ss64.com/bash/pushd.html)

> Save and then change the current directory. With no arguments, pushd exchanges the top two directories.

Usage

```
cd /abc
pushd /xxx    <-- save /abc to environment variables and cd to /xxx
pushd /zzz
pushd +1      <-- cd /xxx
```

[popd](http://ss64.com/bash/popd.html) is to remove the variable (reverse manner)

Comment: This is what I use, but I would recommend `cd -` if the person only wants to jump back and forth between to directories.

Answer (score 7):

[bookmarks.sh](http://lug.fh-swf.de/shell/#bookmarks) provides a bookmark management system for the Bash version 4.0+. It can also use a Midnight Commander hotlist.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is DirB: Directory Bookmarks for Bash well explained in [this *Linux Journal* article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10585)

An example from the article:

```
% cd ~/Desktop
% s d       # save(bookmark) ~/Desktop as d
% cd /tmp   # go somewhere
% pwd
/tmp
% g d       # go to the desktop
% pwd
/home/Desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the question and answers here, I added the lines below to my `~/.bashrc` file.

With this you have a `favdir` command (function) to manage your favorites and a *autocompletion* function to select an item from these favorites.

```
# ---------
# Favorites
# ---------

__favdirs_storage=~/.favdirs
__favdirs=( "$HOME" )

containsElement () {
    local e
    for e in "${@:2}"; do [[ "$e" == "$1" ]] && return 0; done
    return 1
}

function favdirs() {

    local cur
    local IFS
    local GLOBIGNORE

    case $1 in
        list)
            echo "favorite folders ..."
            printf -- ' - %s\n' "${__favdirs[@]}"
            ;;
        load)
            if [[ ! -e $__favdirs_storage ]] ; then
                favdirs save
            fi
            # mapfile requires bash 4 / my OS-X bash vers. is 3.2.53 (from 2007 !!?!).
            # mapfile -t __favdirs < $__favdirs_storage
            IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' __favdirs=($(< $__favdirs_storage))
            ;;
        save)
            printf -- '%s\n' "${__favdirs[@]}" > $__favdirs_storage
            ;;
        add)
            cur=${2-$(pwd)}
            favdirs load
            if containsElement "$cur" "${__favdirs[@]}" ; then
                echo "'$cur' allready exists in favorites"
            else
                __favdirs+=( "$cur" )
                favdirs save
                echo "'$cur' added to favorites"
            fi
            ;;
        del)
            cur=${2-$(pwd)}
            favdirs load
            local i=0
            for fav in ${__favdirs[@]}; do
                if [ "$fav" = "$cur" ]; then
                    echo "delete '$cur' from favorites"
                    unset __favdirs[$i]
                    favdirs save
                    break
                fi
                let i++
            done
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Manage favorite folders."
            echo ""
            echo "usage: favdirs [ list | load | save | add | del ]"
            echo ""
            echo "  list : list favorite folders"
            echo "  load : load favorite folders from $__favdirs_storage"
            echo "  save : save favorite directories to $__favdirs_storage"
            echo "  add  : add directory to favorites [default pwd $(pwd)]."
            echo "  del  : delete directory from favorites [default pwd $(pwd)]."
    esac
} && favdirs load

function __favdirs_compl_command() {
    COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "list load save add del" -- ${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}))
} && complete -o default -F __favdirs_compl_command favdirs

function __favdirs_compl() {
    local IFS=$'\n'
    COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "${__favdirs[*]}" -- ${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}))
}

alias _cd='cd'
complete -F __favdirs_compl _cd
```

Within the last two lines, an alias to change the current directory (with autocompletion) is created. With this alias (`_cd`) you are able to change to one of your favorite directories. *May you wan't to change this alias to something which fits your needs*.

With the function `favdirs` you can manage your favorites (see usage).

```
$ favdirs 
Manage favorite folders.

usage: favdirs [ list | load | save | add | del ]

  list : list favorite folders
  load : load favorite folders from ~/.favdirs
  save : save favorite directories to ~/.favdirs
  add  : add directory to favorites [default pwd /tmp ].
  del  : delete directory from favorites [default pwd /tmp ].
```

Answer (score 1):

@getmizanur
I used your cdb script. I enhanced it slightly by adding bookmarks tab completion. Here's my version of your cdb script.

```
_cdb()
{
    local _script_commands=$(ls -1 ~/.cd_bookmarks/)
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}

    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${_script_commands}" -- $cur) )
}
complete -F _cdb cdb


function cdb() {

    local USAGE="Usage: cdb [-h|-c|-d|-g|-l|-s] [bookmark]\n
    \t[-h or no args] - prints usage help\n
    \t[-c bookmark] - create bookmark\n
    \t[-d bookmark] - delete bookmark\n
    \t[-g bookmark] - goto bookmark\n
    \t[-l] - list bookmarks\n
    \t[-s bookmark] - show bookmark location\n
    \t[bookmark] - same as [-g bookmark]\n
    Press tab for bookmark completion.\n"        

    if  [ ! -e ~/.cd_bookmarks ] ; then
        mkdir ~/.cd_bookmarks
    fi

    case $1 in
        # create bookmark
        -c) shift
            if [ ! -f ~/.cd_bookmarks/$1 ] ; then
                echo "cd `pwd`" > ~/.cd_bookmarks/"$1"
                complete -F _cdb cdb
            else
                echo "Try again! Looks like there is already a bookmark '$1'"
            fi
            ;;
        # goto bookmark
        -g) shift
            if [ -f ~/.cd_bookmarks/$1 ] ; then
                source ~/.cd_bookmarks/"$1"
            else
                echo "Mmm...looks like your bookmark has spontaneously combusted. What I mean to say is that your bookmark does not exist." ;
            fi
            ;;
        # show bookmark
        -s) shift
            if [ -f ~/.cd_bookmarks/$1 ] ; then
                cat ~/.cd_bookmarks/"$1"
            else
                echo "Mmm...looks like your bookmark has spontaneously combusted. What I mean to say is that your bookmark does not exist." ;
            fi
            ;;
        # delete bookmark
        -d) shift
            if [ -f ~/.cd_bookmarks/$1 ] ; then
                rm ~/.cd_bookmarks/"$1" ;
            else
                echo "Oops, forgot to specify the bookmark" ;
            fi
            ;;
        # list bookmarks
        -l) shift
            ls -1 ~/.cd_bookmarks/ ;
            ;;
        -h) echo -e $USAGE ;
            ;;
        # goto bookmark by default
        *)
            if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
                echo -e $USAGE
            elif [ -f ~/.cd_bookmarks/$1 ] ; then
                source ~/.cd_bookmarks/"$1"
            else
                echo "Mmm...looks like your bookmark has spontaneously combusted. What I mean to say is that your bookmark does not exist." ;
            fi
            ;;
    esac
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one that I have written, that is called anc.

https://github.com/tobimensch/anc

Anc stands for anchor, but anc's anchors are really just bookmarks.

It's designed for ease of use and there're multiple ways of navigating, either by giving a text pattern, using numbers, interactively, by going back, or using [TAB] completion.

I'm actively working on it and open to input on how to make it better.

Allow me to paste the examples from anc's github page here:

```
# make the current directory the default anchor:
$ anc s

# go to /etc, then /, then /usr/local and then back to the default anchor:
$ cd /etc; cd ..; cd usr/local; anc

# go back to /usr/local :
$ anc b

# add another anchor:
$ anc a $HOME/test

# view the list of anchors (the default one has the asterisk):
$ anc l
(0) /path/to/first/anchor *
(1) /home/usr/test

# jump to the anchor we just added:
# by using its anchor number
$ anc 1
# or by jumping to the last anchor in the list
$ anc -1

# add multiple anchors:
$ anc a $HOME/projects/first $HOME/projects/second $HOME/documents/first

# use text matching to jump to $HOME/projects/first
$ anc pro fir

# use text matching to jump to $HOME/documents/first
$ anc doc fir

# add anchor and jump to it using an absolute path
$ anc /etc
# is the same as
$ anc a /etc; anc -1

# add anchor and jump to it using a relative path
$ anc ./X11 #note that "./" is required for relative paths
# is the same as
$ anc a X11; anc -1

# using wildcards you can add many anchors at once
$ anc a $HOME/projects/*

# use shell completion to see a list of matching anchors
# and select the one you want to jump to directly
$ anc pro[TAB]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Dmitri Frank's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30864873/1310733) - I have implemented the `cdb` command (aka *cd bookmark*) via simple `alias` (add this line to your `~/.bash_profile`):

```
alias b='cat ~/.cd-bookmarks | grep -v "^\s*#" | grep -v "^\s*$" | fzf'
alias cdb='cd "$(b)"'
```

Create file `~/.cd-bookmarks` and enter your paths, one per line. It supports empty lines and comments via `#`:

```
$ cat ~/.cd-bookmarks
### Devel stuff ###
/Users/pujezdsky/devel/projects/stackoverflow/

### Photo stuff ###
/Users/pujezdsky/Photos/
/Users/pujezdsky/Photos/last-import/
/Users/pujezdsky/Photos/dir with spaces/
```

*Unfortunatelly it does not support `~` expansion so enter full paths.*

Then you are able to do

```
$ cdb
```

And because of `b` alias even some more advanced stuff

```
$ mc `b`
$ cp my-file.txt `b`
$ touch `b`/test.sh
```

Unfortunately though, if you have spaces in your bookmark paths, you have to quote the `` `b` `` call. That makes it less handsome:

```
$mc "`b`"
```

> **Note 1:**
>
> Before you do this, **check if you already have `cdb`, `b` commands / aliases** to avoid their overwrite and malfunction. The easiest way is to use these commands that should return something like `-bash: type: cdb: not found`
>
> ```
> $ type cdb
> $ type b
> ```
>
> **Note 2:**
>
> The `b` alias can be simplified to
>
> ```
> alias b='egrep -v "(^\s*#|^\s*$)" ~/.cd-bookmarks | fzf'
> ```
>
> **Note 3:**
>
> You can also make alias for **adding current folder into your bookmarks**. It is as simple as
>
> ```
> alias ba='pwd >> ~/.cd-bookmarks'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For short term shortcuts, I have a the following in my respective init script (Sorry. I can't find the source right now and didn't bother then):

```
function b() {
    alias $1="cd `pwd -P`"
}
```

**Usage:**

In any directory that you want to bookmark type

```
b THEDIR # <THEDIR> being the name of your 'bookmark'
```

It will create an alias to cd (back) to here.

To return to a 'bookmarked' dir type

```
THEDIR
```

It will run the stored alias and cd back there.

**Caution:** Use only if you understand *that* this might override existing shell aliases and *what* that means.

Answer (score 0):

As practice shows, not so many bookmarks are needed every day.

So we can store them inside the script:

```
function go {
    # go home dir if no params
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then cd ~; return; fi;

    # declare an assoc array with CAPITAL -A switch
    declare -A o
    # declare aliases and targets
    o[apd]=$APPDATA
    o[cli]='/mnt/c/CLI/'
    o[closk]='/mnt/d/JOB/CLosk.Work/Dev._default/'
    o[ds]='/mnt/d/JOB/DS/'
    o[gh]='/mnt/d/Alpha/GitHub/'
    o[pf]='/mnt/c/Program Files/'
    o[wsa]='/mnt/d/JOB/WSA/Dev/'

    # here we go
    if [ ${o[$1]+_} ]; then cd "${o[$1]}"; fi
}
```

Using associative array let the list of links to be corrected with ease.

As you can see this script successfully used under Windows also.
I'm using this script under CentOS and Ubuntu too. With other links of course.

Also, I'm using this:

```
alias ~='go'
```

So:

```
~ # go to home dir
~ apd # go to system Application Data folder
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function some time ago in ~/.bashrc:

```
cdfav() {
    local favfile
    local tmpfavfile
    local match

    favfile=~/.cdfav
    if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
        awk '{print i++ " " $0}' $favfile
        return $?
    fi

    if [ "$1" = "-a" ]; then
        readlink -f $2 >> $favfile
        return $?
    fi

    if [ "$1" = "-d" ]; then
        tmpfavfile=/tmp/.cdfav-tmp-${$}
        awk '{print i++ " " $0}' $favfile | sed "/$2/d" | cut -f2- -d' ' > $tmpfavfile
        mv $tmpfavfile $favfile
        return 0
    fi

    if [ ! -e $favfile ]; then
      return 1
    fi

    match=$(awk '{print i++ " " $0}' $favfile | grep "$1" | head -1 | cut -f2- -d' ')
    if [ "$match" = "" ]; then
      return 1
    fi

    cd $match
    return $?
}
```

Usage examples:

```
~$ cdfav # lists favorite dirs
0 /home/user/dev/linux/
1 /home/user/dev/linux/references/v7unix
~$ cdfav ^1 # match 1 dir
~/dev/linux$ cdfav refe # no need for typing the whole dir name/path. The directory will be the first matched
~/dev/linux/references/v7unix$
```

I can add a (current) directory to my list with "-a ."

```
~/dev/linux/references/v7unix$ cd v7/
~/dev/linux/references/v7unix/v7$ cdfav -a .
~/dev/linux/references/v7unix/v7$ cdfav
0 /home/user/dev/linux/
1 /home/user/dev/linux/references/v7unix
2 /home/user/dev/linux/references/v7unix/v7
```

or remove a directories containing substring/matching regexp (with gnu grep on my machine) like this:

```
~/dev/linux/references/v7unix/v7$ cdfav -d v7
~/dev/linux/references/v7unix/v7$ cdfav
0 /home/user/dev/linux/
```

Have not tested with other shells like oksh yet, but I think it will work there also without much tweaking.